# How to register an protocol/deep links to my Electron App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, protocols

> **Error launching app: "Unable to find Electron app at..."**

I'm using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) and I'm not able to create a handler that opens my electron app in development mode.

I've read the [Deep Links](https://www.electronjs.org/pt/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app) and [Protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/pt/docs/latest/api/protocol) documentation and I still couldn't get it to work!

Following the [Deep Links](https://www.electronjs.org/pt/docs/latest/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app) documentation I was able to open the app after it was packaged into an .exe, but I can't debug and catch this event and work on the front-end.

In development mode this error appears whenever I access the handler:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkj8Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by adding on main.js:

```
if (!app.isDefaultProtocolClient('electron-handler')) {  
  app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('electron-handler')
}
```

and this on package.json:

```
"build": {
  ...
  "protocols": {
    "name": "my electron handler",
    "schemes": [
      "electron-handler"
    ]
  },
}
```